# Do High Triglycerides Invalidate Tests for Infections?

Tags: hematology

Blood donation websites tell you to avoid eating fats a few days before the donation, because when there is a lot of fat in the blood, they can't test for infectious diseases and must discard the blood.

Does that mean that if you have, say, high triglycerides, the result of an infection disease blood test will be invalid? Say you test syphilis, HIV, etc. If at the same time you get a result of high triglycerides, does that mean the results of infectious diseases can't be trusted?

Comment: You might want to look at [this article about how Lipemia causes interference with some tests](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3936974/).